# Submenu Disappearance

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been creating a navbar, and made some drop downs. For some reason, my submenu/sub or nested navbar doesn't seem to actually stay when I try to hover upon it. Is there something I should do to actually enable it? I've tried using jQuery (as shown below), using the + operator in CSS, creating a separate, hidden div to try to maintain the submenu's appearance, etc. Nothing really seems to work, and I'm slightly stumped. For the jQuery example below, it says submenu is not defined, but I don't really know how to fix it as I am not extremely frank with the error, and either way it still happens to not display the submenu.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;

  }

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  
  .navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 39px;

    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .navbar a.active {
    background-color: #04aa6d;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    /* transition: height 0.25s; */
  }
  
  .navbar a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu {
    /* ---Check jQuery--- */
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    left:100%;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
  }

  .dropdown-submenu:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }

  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  

  .collapse {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(80, 78, 78);
    color: #fffefed7;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 5.5rem #525c5c, 0em 0em 0.9em #ffffff6b;
    cursor: pointer; 
    top: 4.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: rgba(32, 30, 30, 0.863);
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;  
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    right: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out 1ms;
  }

  .collapse:hover {  
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  }

  .collapse:active {  
    transform: translateY(1px);
    background-color: rgb(109, 103, 103);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "cssjavascript/style.css"/>
    <script src="cssjavascript/addon.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

    <style>
        h3 {
             left: 2%;
             max-width: 200px;
             padding: 20px;
             margin: 20px;
        }  
        

        p {
            max-width: 200px;
             padding: 20px;
             margin: 20px;
             word-wrap: break-word;  
        }

    </style>
    <title>Contact Page</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">FAQ</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
   
          <button class="dropbtn">Coding &#9660;
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a class = "parentdrop" href="#">Web Development &#9654;</a> 
          <div class = "dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#">HTML</a>
            <a href="#">CSS</a>
            <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
          </div>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div> 

        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>

        <button title = "Collapse Navbar" class = "collapse"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
            expand_less
            </span></button>
      </div>


      <h1 style = "position: relative; display: flexbox; text-align:center; width: auto;">Contact Page</h1>

    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/cryptoandcraze@gmail.com" method="POST" class = "formDiv">
        <input type="text" name="_subject" placeholder = "Write your subject here" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder = "Email Address" required>
        <!-- Change redirect value from local IP address to actual website link later -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/thankyou.html">
        <input type = "text" name = "message" placeholder = "Write your message here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      let submenu =  document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-submenu");
      
        $(".parentdrop").on({

        mouseenter: function () {
          for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "block";
        },

        mouseleave: function () {
          for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      });

   });

    $(".dropdown-submenu").on({

      mouseenter: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "block";
      },

    mouseleave: function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) submenu[i].style.display = "none";
      }
   });

    
      </script>
      
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you have any questions of the code, please don't hesitate to comment/ping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, when the mouse enters the `.dropdown-submenu`, a `mouseleave` event is fired for the `.parentdrop` element which triggers which hides the `.dropdown-submenu`. All we need to do is to add similar `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers to the `.dropdown-submenu` to show and hide itself, respectively.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.parentdrop').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      const $submenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-submenu');
      $submenu.show();
    },
    mouseleave: function (event) {
      const $submenu = $(this).next('.dropdown-submenu');
      $submenu.hide();
    }
  });
  
  $('.dropdown-submenu').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $(this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   margin: 0;

 }

 .navbar {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
 }

 .navbar a {
   float: left;
   font-size: 39px;

   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .navbar a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
 }

 .navbar a.active {
   background-color: #04aa6d;
   color: white;
 }

 .dropdown {
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 .dropdown .dropbtn {
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   background-color: inherit;
   font-family: inherit;
   margin: 0;
   /* transition: height 0.25s; */
 }

 .navbar a:hover,
 .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
   background-color: red;
 }

 .dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   z-index: 1;
 }

 .dropdown-content a {
   float: none;
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
 }

 .dropdown-submenu {
   /* ---Check jQuery--- */
   display: none;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 100%;
   top: 20px;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   position: absolute;
 }

 .dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
 }


 .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
 }



 .collapse {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: rgb(80, 78, 78);
   color: #fffefed7;
   box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 5.5rem #525c5c, 0em 0em 0.9em #ffffff6b;
   cursor: pointer;
   top: 4.5%;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-color: rgba(32, 30, 30, 0.863);
   display: flex;
   /* or inline-flex */
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   right: 50%;
   transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out 1ms;
 }

 .collapse:hover {
   background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
 }

 .collapse:active {
   transform: translateY(1px);
   background-color: rgb(109, 103, 103);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">FAQ</a>
  <div class="dropdown">

    <button class="dropbtn">Coding &#9660;
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="parentdrop" href="#">Web Development &#9654;</a>
      <div class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">HTML</a>
        <a href="#">CSS</a>
        <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>

  <button title="Collapse Navbar" class="collapse"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
      expand_less
    </span></button>
</div>


<h1 style="position: relative; display: flexbox; text-align:center; width: auto;">Contact Page</h1>

<form action="https://formsubmit.co/cryptoandcraze@gmail.com" method="POST" class="formDiv">
  <input type="text" name="_subject" placeholder="Write your subject here" required>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
  <!-- Change redirect value from local IP address to actual website link later -->
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://127.0.0.1:5500/thankyou.html">
  <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here..." required>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is a great example, but I think for some reason it groups all the elements together. Is there an iterative method which still respects each child/individual div? When you hover upon the elements, it for some reason hovers on all the elements (as you can tell by it triggering the hover animation on every single element) instead of each individual one.

Comment: If you could fix this small aspect I would gladly accept this answer along with an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: @MyInfo There is a CSS rule that is applying a background-color of `#ddd` to the `.dropdown-submenu when it is hovered. I can remove that from the snippet.

Comment: Oh shoot! That's my fault! I forgot to apply it to each individual element. Let me try to edit it really quickly.

Comment: Yup! Works perfectly fine after modifying it to `.submenu a:hover` instead of `.submenu:hover` Thanks! Enjoy your free rep points!